# Python, one tests affect the other one

Tags: python, logging, pytest, code-coverage, test-coverage

There are have two tests. First one checks if logging module loggs all informations into log file:

```py
    def test_logging_into_many_modules(self):
        """Assure logger is properly used in many files"""

        run(1, 1, False)
        with open("darwin.log") as log_file:
            content = log_file.read()
            # Check if log takes place in main modules
            self.assertIn("libs.population", content)
            self.assertIn("libs.individual", content)
            self.assertIn("libs.mutation", content)
            self.assertIn("libs.selection", content)
            self.assertIn("libs.chromosome", content)
            self.assertIn("libs.crossover", content)
```

`run()` method just executes my whole program.

Also I have test to achieve 100% test coverage. I'm testing `if __name__ == '__main__'` block in main executable file `darwin.py`:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This test:

```py
    @mock.patch("darwin.run")
    @mock.patch("argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args")
    def test__name____main__(self, mock_argparse, mock_run):
        """Test if __name__ == '__main__' block code is executed."""
        mock_argparse.return_value = argparse.Namespace(
            populationSize=1, numberOfIterations=1, sendMail=False)
        loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader("__main__", "darwin.py")
        mod = types.ModuleType(loader.name)
        loader.exec_module(mod)

        with open("darwin.log") as log_file:
            content = log_file.read()
            self.assertIn("__main__", content)
```

I run tests using `pytest` library. Pytest run tests alphabetically so `test__name__main` will be tested first. If I run this tests seperately, everything both pass. Also if test order is `test_logging_into_many_modules` first and `test__name__main__` second - everyting works as excpected. The problem is when `test__name__main__` is executed first, it somehow breaks the `FileHandler` from logging module and nothing can be logged into `darwin.log` file.

Any ideas why this is happening?
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Probably because `darwin.run` remains patched - add smth like `print(run)` to `test_logging_into_many_modules` and rerun the tests with the `-s` switch - what is printed, a `<MagicMock ...>`?

Comment: Nope, I've already tried that. Actually `None` is printed